# Compare each row with all rows in data frame and save results in list for each row

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, fuzzywuzzy

I try to compare each row with all rows in a pandas dataframe with `fuzzywuzzy.fuzzy.partial_ratio() >= 85` and write the results in a list for each row.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'name': ['dog', 'cat', 'mad cat', 'good dog', 'bad dog', 'chicken']})
```

I want to use a pandas function with the `fuzzywuzzy` library to get the result:

```
id  name     match_id_list
1   dog      [4, 5]
2   cat      [3, ]
3   mad cat  [2, ]
4   good dog [1, 5]
5   bad dog  [1, 4]
6   chicken  []
```

But I don't understand how to get this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first step would be to find the indices that match the condition for a given `name`. Since `partial_ratio` only takes strings, we `apply` it to the dataframe:

```
name = 'dog'
df.apply(lambda row: (partial_ratio(row['name'], name) >= 85), axis=1)
```

We can then use `enumerate` and list comprehension to generate the list of `true` indices in the boolean array:

```
matches = df.apply(lambda row: (partial_ratio(row['name'], name) >= 85), axis=1)
[i for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x]
```

Let's put all this inside a function:

```
def func(name):
    matches = df.apply(lambda row: (partial_ratio(row['name'], name) >= 85), axis=1)
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x]
```

We can now apply the function to the entire dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda row: func(row['name']), axis=1)
```