# Pandas - Compare single row with all rows in same dataframe

Tags: python

I would like to add a column to an existing dataframe which shows a count value. The count value should compare a value in a given row versus all rows in another column.

In my example I want to find the number of times a value in the entire 'end_date' column is earlier than current 'start_date' column.  Adding the count to the dataframe like so:

```
        start_date   end_date   count
1       2020-09-2   2020-09-3     1
2       2020-09-6   2020-09-7     3
3       2020-09-4   2020-09-5     2
4       2020-09-1   2020-09-1     0
```

I have tried

```
df['count'] = (df[df['end_date']<df['start_date']]).count()
```

but this results in the count column being 0 for all rows as the start_date is always less than the end_date within any one row.

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve this?

Comment: Are all the values numbers?

Comment: I have updated the example to better represent my actual problem

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459316/compare-each-row-with-all-rows-in-data-frame-and-save-results-in-list-for-each-r) answers your question

Comment: `(df[df['end_date']<df['start_date']])` gives you a boolean array and with numpy.sum() you can get the number of `True` (as True in python is the integer 1 and False is the integer 0). Then `np.sum((df[df['end_date']<df['start_date']]))` gives you the answer

Comment: @aerijman, this gives the same problem as proposed in the question using count()

Comment: Now I see, then do this within a loop on `itertuples()` or just iterating over the `index`. Ping me if you want me to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want `count[i]` = number of times `compare[:]` is less than `ref[i]`.
You did `count[:]` = number of times `compare[i] < ref[i]`

A straightforward way is to iterate over the rows and calculate individually.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[i, 'count'] = (df['end_date'] < row['start_date']).sum()
```

`(df['end_date'] < row[i, 'start_date'])` returns a column of `True` or `False` depending on whether the condition is satisfied. `.sum()` takes `True` values as 1 and `False` values as 0.

Comment: This would presumably only work with a integer based index.

Comment: @ckeiderling The important part of the code is that you iterate over the rows, compare the iteration row with all other rows, and assign the result to the iteration row. If your indexing is different, it's trivial to get the "active ingredient" of the code to fit your requirements.

Comment: @ckeiderling, I've edited my answer to use `iterrows()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an outer join

```
counts = (
    pd.merge(
        df[["start_date"]].assign(temp=1),
        df[["end_date"]].assign(temp=1),
        on="temp",
        how="outer",
    )
    .query("start_date>end_date")
    .groupby("start_date")
    .temp.count()
)

df = df.merge(counts, on="start_date", how="left").fillna(0, downcast="infer")
```

Comment: This works best so far, it's still quite a long solution to what seems like a simple problem.

Comment: I've made it shorter, not sure how to reduce it further

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'start_date': ['2020-09-02', '2020-09-06', '2020-09-04', '2020-09-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
df['count'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index,'count'] = df[df['start_date'] < row['start_date']].count()[1]
print (df)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_